# Show/hide an image for a forwarded html email

Tags: html, css, email, email-client, forwarding

I'm trying to show/hide an image (one for desktop and one for mobile) on an html email when forwarded. The method I use works great for most email clients (the exception being Lotus), however, both images show if the email is forwarded. I know the simplest solution is to just use one image, but if there is a solution where I can use show/hide that works when forwarded I would like to know. The html:

```
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="display:block; outline:none; text-decoration:none; -ms- 
             interpolation-mode: bicubic;" class="hide">
              <a href="ops_link"> 
               <img border="0" width="100%" src="ops_desktop_pic" alt="#" 
               class="hide" > 
             </a>
            </td>
            <td style="display:none; font-size:0; line-height:0; mso-hide: 
            all;max-height: 0; max-width: 0; width:0; -ms-interpolation-mode: 
            bicubic;" class="show">
             <a href="ops_link">
              <img border="0" width="100%" height="357"  src="ops_mobile_pic" 
              alt="#" class="show">
             </a>
            </td>
           </tr>
    </table>
```

and the CSS:

```
    @media (max-width: 650px){
     .hide {
    display:none!important;
    width:0px!important;
    height: 0px!important;
    overflow:hidden!important;
    line-height: 0px!important;
    font-size:0px!important;
}
    .show {
    display:block!important;
    max-height: none !important;
    max-width:100% !important;
    line-height: 1.5 !important;
    width:100%!important;
    height:auto!important;
    font-size: 100%;
    mso-hide: none;
}
}
```

Comment: did you manage to find a way for this?

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as I know it's impossible to account for a)forwarded emails or b)certain versions of OWA. This code works very well for original messages but you will run into those problems.